# Select a value in dropdown list displayed in JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a dropdown list which is being displayed using JSP using Spring web services.

The list in generated in the controller with the following codes:

```
List<String> abcList = abcManager.getAbcList(a, b, c);
referenceData.put("abcList", abcList);
```

The above list is called in JSP with the following code:

```
<form:label path="abcType" cssClass="sectionTitle">AbcType:</form:label>
<span class="error">*</span><br>
<form:select path="abcType" onChange="updateXyzTypeByAbcType(this, 'xyzType');">
<form:option value="0" label="Please Select:"/>
<form:options items="${abcList}"/>
</form:select>
<form:errors path="abcType" cssClass="error"/>
```

The codes work fine, the list gets generated as it is supposed to, no problem there. However, here is what I want to do (and not being able to do so);

Suppose in abcList, there are 5 items - m, n, o, p and q. When the list is displayed, I want the system to select "n" automatically. Right now, I get "Please Select:" and then the remaining 5 options in the dropdown. I would want to get "n" selected, and in the dropdown - the remaining 4 options, as well as a "Please Select:" option.

Let me know if I need to provide something else to better understand the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use javascript and make the desired option selected by defalut while loading.